# Underscore.js groupBy and Contains

Tags: javascript, arrays, group-by, underscore.js

I have two arrays of values one is needed to groupBy the other one so:

```
var countries = ['IT', 'BE', 'SE'];
var items = [
   {amount: 9, country: 'IT'}, 
   {amount: 5, country: 'US'}, 
   {amount: 4, country: 'BE'}, 
   {amount: 3, country: 'IT'}, 
   {amount: 9, country: 'BE'}, 
   {amount: 9, country: 'SE'}
];

var groupedItems = _.groupBy(items, function (item) {
    // Hint please
});
```

I need to group `countries` by the following rules:

- group if `item.country === 'IT'`
- group if `item.country !== 'IT' && _.contains(countries, item.country)`
- group if `!_.contains(countries, item.country)`

Any hint?

Comment: Add those rules to the function and return an appropriate value if a condition is met e.g. return 1 if condition 1 is met, 2 if condition 2 is met etc.

Comment: Changing the value returned for each group was the missing piece. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was pretty easy thanks to the hint in the comment:

```
_.groupBy(function (item) {
    if (item.country !== 'IT' && _.contains(countries, item.country)) {
        return 'IT';
    } else if (item.country === 'IT') {
        return 'UE';
    } else if (!_.contains(countries, item.country)) {
        return 'EXTRA-UE';
    }
});
```